# What methods do I need to implement for my matrix-like class in R?

Tags: r, oop, matrix, interface

I'm designing a class in R that has a lot of the same behaviors as a 2-dimensional matrix: it can be subsetted by row or column, it has dimnames, etc. So I want it to support all the "standard" matrix operations such as `rownames`, `[`, and so on. But I'm not sure what all of these method names are, and I'm not sure which of them I need to implement. For instance, do I need to implement `rownames` and `rownames<-` explicitly, or is it sufficient to implement `dimnames` and `dimanmes<-`? Basically, is there a list somewhere of all the functions that one would have to implement for a class to act like a 2-dimensional matrix-like thing?

Comment: Or just use the built in matrix.  I'll bet it's better than anything you'd write.

Comment: I'm not making a matrix. I'm making something that has some of the same behaviors as a matrix, but also other behaviors and properties as well.

Comment: unless you want it **not** to do something a `matrix`-class object does, why not assign both `matrix` and `ryans_matrix` classes to it?

Comment: Well, I want it to be subsettable in 2 dimensions, and I want it to have gettable and settable dimnames. For the sake of argument, let's say the class is set of several identically-sized matrices that all need to be subsetted in lockstep, and that share a common set of dimnames. So it's not really a matrix, and I need to implement all my own methods because of course the `[` method for matrices isn't going to work unmodified.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just extend the `matrix` class? You can add a bunch of other stuff without getting in the way of existing methods. That would be a whole lot easier than rewriting all the basics.

For generics, you can do

```
> methods(class = "matrix")
 [1] anyDuplicated.matrix as.data.frame.matrix as.raster.matrix*   
 [4] boxplot.matrix       determinant.matrix   duplicated.matrix   
 [7] edit.matrix*         head.matrix          isSymmetric.matrix  
[10] relist.matrix*       subset.matrix        summary.matrix      
[13] tail.matrix          unique.matrix
```

For something like `rownames`, the help specifies that it works on "matrix-like objects", so depending on *how* different your class is, it may just work. You can look at the code to see how things work, in the case of `rownames`, it looks like if you define `dimnames` and maybe `NROW` you're good. The bad news is that, because it works on "matrix-like objects" rather than being a method for the matrix class, it that you'll be hard-pressed to find a list of other such functions.

Comment: Your last sentence describes my problem exactly.